# Read Glue Metadata using Lambda Fucntion and Push it to RDS PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I am new to Lambda Function and need some help with writing a Lambda Function, which will access Glue Catalog Database Metadata and dump that into a RDS PostgreSQL database table.
Please let me know if there is any Python code for Lambda that can support this use case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read the [AWS Glue Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/index.html)? Did you try anything yet? Please let us know if you have a _specific_ question.

Comment: Hi John Thanks for the follow up. I haven't tried anything yet. So for example, I found this API - [aws glue get-tables --database-name 'tempdb'] which I think will provide me details of each table in the glue database. This is something I can start with. Now to use this command in the Lambda Python code is there a template where i can insert this code and the lambda will show me the desired output? Something like you start off by importing boto3 and then creating a service and then insert this API code for that service and then print the output etc. etc. Thanks

Comment: Yep, that's the way to do it. Just use the [Glue — Boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html) for reference. I'd recommend coding it on your own computer first since it's easier to debug, and then copy it to an AWS Lambda function. Or, just put `print()` statements in the Lambda function and look at the output in CloudWatch Logs to see what is happening.